# How to exchange the items of enumeration by interating only once?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, enumeration

I'm trying to exchange the ordering of particular items of an `IEnumerable`.

Given an `IEnumerable<int> a;` of the elements:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

and what I want to do is write a exchange iterator which resulting `a.Exchange(1, 2)` in:

> 1, 3, 2, 4, 5

But I don't want the enumerable be iterated more than once with this simple purpose. What I have so far is:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Exchange<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int index1, int index2) {
    var i=0;

    foreach(var y in source) {
        if(index1==i) {
            var j=0;

            foreach(var x in source) {
                if(index2==j) {
                    yield return x;
                    break;
                }

                ++j;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(index2==i) {
                var j=0;

                foreach(var x in source) {
                    if(index1==j) {
                        yield return x;
                        break;
                    }

                    ++j;
                }
            }
            else {
                yield return y;
            }
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
```

Here's a assumption that `index1` and `index2` wouldn't exceed the elements of the enumerable. The code done the work of exchange(the ordering) in most cases, but it does iterate more than once. Note `index1` and `index2` might not be the real indices of `source`, they would be the `Mth` and `Nth` element when the enumeration occurs.

`ToArray` or `ToList` may also increase the times of iteration.

Comment: Is ToList not an option?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: Possibly not for this case ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WOLOG assume that `index1` is less than `index2`.

Make your own enumerator; don't use `foreach`.

For elements up to `index1`, iterate normally and yield each.

Then when you hit `index1`, allocate an array big enough to hold the elements between `index1` through `index2` -- that is, including the `index1`th element, but not the `index2`th element.

Read the elements into that array using your enumerator.

Now read the `index2`th element and yield it.

Your enumerator is now set to one beyond `index2`.

Now yield everything in the array *except* the `index1`th element.

Then yield the `index1`th element.

Then yield the rest of the elements normally.

Don't forget to call `Dispose` on the enumerator when you're done.

Comment: +1. Nice candidate for MoreLINQ, even though I can't find out any good application for this in real life.

Comment: Why shouldn't one use `foreach`?

Comment: @Sphinxxx: It is certainly possible, but take a look at dasblinkenlight's answer. Though you could write that thing as a foreach loop, notice how he takes advantage of the fact that he has the enumerator in hand to fill up the temporary storage array. As an exercise, try writing the code both ways and see how you like each technique.

Comment: Thank you very much! dasblinkenlight and p.s.w.g have the different approach of implementation of the answer, which are also good.

Comment: @Sphinxxx: Well it looks like we have two different implementations, one using foreach and one using an explicit enumerator. Both are pretty easy to read I think, so it turns out to be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Exchange<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int index1, int index2) 
{
    return source.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                 .OrderBy(p => p.i == index1 ? index2 : p.i == index2 ? index1 : p.i)
                 .Select(p => p.x);
}

new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Exchange(1, 2); // { 1, 3, 2, 4, 5 }
```

To do it without an `OrderBy`, I think it would look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Exchange<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int index1, int index2) 
{
    if (index1 > index2)
    {
        int x = index1;
        index1 = index2;
        index2 = x;
    }

    int index = 0;
    List<T> itemsBetweenIndexes = new List<T>();
    bool betweenIndexes = false;
    T temp = default(T);
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if (!betweenIndexes)
        {
            if (index == index1)
            {
                temp = item;
                betweenIndexes = true;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (index == index2)
            {
                betweenIndexes = false;
                yield return item;
                foreach(var x in itemsBetweenIndexes)
                {
                    yield return x;
                }
                itemsBetweenIndexes.Clear();
                yield return temp;
            }
            else
            {
                itemsBetweenIndexes.Add(item);
            }
        }

        index++;
    }
}
```

Initially, this loops through looking for the item at `index1` yielding every item until it finds it. Once found it begins adding items to an internal queue until it finds `index2`. At that point it yields the item at `index2`, followed by every item in the queue, in order, followed by the item at `index1`. It then goes back to looking for `index1` (which it won't find) until it reaches the end of the list.

Comment: won't `OrderBy` consume all sequence, which is opposite to what OP wanted? Isn't *ToList() -> Swap by index -> return* would be more efficient?

Comment: The code tooks me a long time to read, and I'm thinkg about why not invoke `source.Exchange(index2, index1)` directly when `index1` is greater than `index2` ..

Comment: @KenKin Yeah, you could do that too. It's just a matter of taste, really.

Comment: Nice solution. My only comment would be that the "big else" braces and indentation are unnecessary; I'd be inclined to write this as `if (!betweenindexes) ... else if (index == index2) ... else`. But this is just a stylistic point.

Comment: @KenKin Actually, I was mostly just trying to make it as easy as possible to understand the logic. It could definitely be written in a more compact style.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform this operation without iterating the original more than once, you would need to store the content of the subsequence between the indexes that you are swapping.

Here is how you can implement the algorithm (I renamed `index1` and `index2` to `smallerIndex` and `greaterIndex`):

```
using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
    IList<T> saved = new List<T>(greaterIndex-smallerIndex+1);
    int index = 0;
    while (e.MoveNext()) {
        // If we're outside the swapped indexes, yield return the current element
        if (index < smallerIndex || index > greaterIndex) {
            index++;
            yield return e.Current;
        } else if (index == smallerIndex) {
            var atSmaller = e.Current;
            // Save all elements starting with the current one into a list;
            // Continue until you find the last index, or exhaust the sequence.
            while (index != greaterIndex && e.MoveNext()) {
                saved.Add(e.Current);
                index++;
            }
            // Make sure we're here because we got to the greaterIndex,
            // not because we've exhausted the sequence
            if (index == greaterIndex) {
                // If we are OK, return the element at greaterIndex
                yield return e.Current;
            }
            // Enumerate the saved items
            for (int i = 0 ; i < saved.Count-1 ; i++) {
                yield return saved[i];
            }
            // Finally, return the item at the smallerIndex
            yield return atSmaller;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/YSh9im).

Comment: You missed the last step: don't forget to call Dispose on the enumerator when you're done.

Comment: There're three answers technically equivalent .. ?

Comment: @KenKin Correct, they are. The ones with the code approached the problem a little differently from each other (my code is very close to what Eric described in plain English, while p.s.w.g's answer does not use explicit enumerators). However, all three solutions use identical amount of storage at runtime, and iterate the input exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one pass by creating a `List<T>` and then returning it as an `IEnumerable<T>` type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Exchange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index1, int index2)
{
    // TODO: check index1 and index2 are in bounds of List/Enumerable
    var result = source.ToList(); // single enumeration
    // Swap vars
    var temp = result[index1];
    result[index1] = result[index2];
    result[index2] = temp;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I guess enumeration on `a.Exchange(0, 1).Exchange(1, 2)` may iterate the whole elements at least two times ..